# Returning an object from a Spring Batch job / processor

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch job that reads in a very large fixed length file and maps it just fine to an object. Validated all of the data in the associated processing task.

Being rather new to Spring and Spring Batch I am wondering if it is possible to get out of the job, a fully populated object to be used in a particular case when I am running the job as part of another process ( that I would like to have access to the data).

I realize that I could do the above without Batch, and it seems to be designed with scope limitations for its purpose.

I could serialize the objects in the processor and go that route but for my immediate satisfaction I am hoping there is a way to get around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my @configuration class for the batch processing, I created a class variable (it is a list of the object I want to get back) and instantiated with the no arg constructor.

My Step, ItemReader, LineMapper are setup to use a list for input. The custom FieldSetMapper takes that list instantiated from the constructor as a parameter and adds to the list as the file is read and mapped. Similarly my custom ItemProcessor takes the list as input and returns it.

Finally I created a ReturnObjectList bean that returns the populated list.

In my main I cast the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext getbean to the list of that object type. I am now able to use the list of objects generated from the fixed file in the scope of my main application.

Not sure if this is a healthy work around in terms of how Spring Java config is supposed to work, but it does give me what I need.